# Getting AdWords search term

Tags: asp.net, google-ads-api

We would like to know how we can get the AdWords search term when a user clicks on one or our ads and lands on our landing page. We inspected the `Request.UrlReferrer` value, but it doesn't contain it. We have auto-tagging turned-on on our account, so it should be sent in the utm_term url parameter, but that parameter is not being sent to my landing page.

Answer (score 0):

This [blog post](http://www.ppchero.com/google-analytics-loses-paid-search-queries-time-to-panic/) provides useful info about recent changes to Google Analytics and how to obtain this information.

You can also use the AdWords API's [SEARCH_QUERY_PERFORMANCE_REPORT](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports#search-query).